# Confusion about multithreading in Python and C

Tags: python, c, multithreading

AFAIK, Python, using `import thread`, (or C#) doesn't do "real" multithreading, meaning all threads run on 1 CPU core.

But in C, using pthreads in linux, You get real multithreading.

Is this true ?

Assuming it is true, is there any difference between them when you have only 1 CPU core (I have it in a VM)?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with Python using C#? IronPython? Or C# using Threading?

Comment: @AndreasKlebinger Where did I mention that?!

Comment: > AFAIK, Python, using import thread, **(or C#)**

Comment: By the way, I don't think that C# (or any other .NET language) has the same problem of Python with threads. But I'm not a dotnetous-man. Also because IronPython is one of the Python interpreters which has no GIL.

Comment: @AndreasKlebinger Read it like this: Python (using `import thread`) or C# (using whatever) ... @Faust My colleague told my that. I was surprised about this, too.

Comment: Hes right for Python and wrong about C# then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python uses something called a Global Interpreter Lock which means multiple python threads can only run within one native Thread.

There is more documentation in the official Docs here: https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock

There shouldn't be a real performance difference on single core systems. On multicore systems the difference will varie based on what you do. (I/O is for the most part not affected by the GIL).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of how it works C# internally,  but for CPython (the "official" python interpreter) it is true: threads are not *really* parallel due to [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock).
Other implementation of the Python interpreter do not suffer of this problem (like C's pthreads library).
Howevere if you only have 1 CPU you won't notice any difference.
As a side note: if you need real parallelism in CPython you could you `multiprocessing` module, which uses processes instead of threads.

EDIT:

Also `thread` module is a bit deprecated, you should consider using `threading`.

Comment: `multiprocessing` is a bit harder to implement, compared to `theading`. Thanks for the tip about `threading`, I'm off to google!